# Store 2D data matrix on a Turing Machine tape

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I have a potentially infinite N*N matrix used by some arbitrary programming language. In this programming language each field of the matrix contains one whole number (zero to infinity). And in this programming language, we can only access the fields of this array by moving one step over one of the axis and then reading the current value. The value of the current field can also be incremented or decremented.

Now my task is to implement this as a Turing Machine. By default, the tape alphabet contains {0, 1, blank} but can be extended. I can also use multiple tapes.

Now the problem I have is in how the whole number should be stored on the tape. I cannot designate a certain amount of "bits" for each number, as the maximum values is not limited.
I am also not sure how the final turing machine will be accessing these values effectively.

Is there an effective way to achieve this? Essentially I should be able to transform any code from the said language into a Turing machine, but I am oblivious as to how.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want *some* representation, here's an example.

You can represent the matrix itself as a delimited string where delimited tokens represent rows. You can extend this by including the matrix dimensions at the front of the input string before some special separator token. For efficiency and simplicity, you could use other tapes to have ready access to the matrix dimensions, and yet other tapes to keep track of your current coordinates within the matrix. So, your TM's state might look like this:

```
tape 1: 4,4:0101;1100;1101;0010.
tape 2: 4                ^
tape 3: 4
tape 4: 2
tape 5: 3
```

With this setup, you can tell whether you're allowed to move to the right or left, up or down; and you can move however you like (moving up or down is equivalent to moving left or right by a number of spaces equal to tape 2's value).